# Add custom tab in admin woocommerce product

Tags: php, wordpress, class, woocommerce

I am trying to get a custom tab added in woocommerce admin panel for the products section but it's not showing up. Can someone steer me in the right direction? I'm trying to do it as a class.

```
<?php
/*
    Plugin Name: Cdog Woocomerce Product Options
    Description: Allow a customer to order several different options of one product under one line item.
    Version: 1.0
    Author: Clint Chaney
*/

class cdog_product_options
{

    public function __construct()
    {
        add_action( 'woocommerce_product_write_panel_tabs', array( &$this, 'create_admin_tab' ) );
    }

    /* this creates the tab in the products section in the admin panel */
    public function create_admin_tab()
    {
        ?>
        <li class="cdog_product_options_tab"><a href="#cdog_product_options"><?php _e('Product Options', 'woocommerce'); ?></a></li>
        <?
    }

} // end class

$cdog_product_options = new cdog_product_options();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well the solution was simple and I feel dumb but I forgot to create the object at the end.

Added this to the code above

```
$cdog_product_options = new cdog_product_options();
```